# Updating a Laravel project in godaddy cpanel, but no update seen in the page?

Tags: javascript, php, cpanel, project

I am just filling in for a friend at work and I am not familiar with how updating a live Laravel php project in GoDaddy live serve?

Goal:

Update an image URL in a js file, via Godaddy Cpanel.

Attempt:

the js file is located in the public folder, I made a change there but It is not updating the image link in the live site.

Question:

How do you go about making this change in the javascript file(in the public folder) and updating the live site for a Laravel PHP?

Comment: it's probably some kind of cache system in place. Either within the laravel application or the server. Have you checked any of these?

Comment: I was able to find a way to update what I wanted, but it seems like it will be temporary. I went to the public folder(public_html/public) and change the code there and it seems to work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If I may ask if I wanted to use ssh to clear cache, how do I go about doing that? what folder do I target in the terminal to use the `php artisan cache:clear`?

Comment: If you are gonna ssh in and do it, you need to run the command in the parent folder of doc root, for a standard install of Laravel. The folder will have a file called "artisan" in it.

Comment: If the js file, is a bundled js file, next time your js is bundled you may loose your updates. Are you using some sort of front end framework or build system?

Comment: Also, if all you did was  modify the contents of a js file, not it's name, than I'm pretty sure we can rule out a CDN, now we just need to understand what kind of local caching is involved if any.

Comment: I am not using any framework, I am just editing straight from the server (GoDaddy Cpanel). the changes I made are for a non-CDN js. How do I go about knowing what local caching is involve and going about clear it up. Thank you for all the help

Answer (score 0):

You may want to ensure there is not some sort of caching being employed. Laravel has some artisan commands for clearing the cache.

Failing that, chances are you have to clear the Blade and Asset caches... And if the site uses a CDN, such as cloudflare you will need to purge that file from the CDN cache.

Also, ensure your browser is not caching a previous version of the asset.

You can easily see if it's related to assets caching  by changing the asset name, ensure to update any references to the asset in any templates or partials and then check, or you could also try "busting" the cache by adding "?" To the asset url, as generally queried paths are not cached.

Comment: I manage to go straight source via the public folder located at public_html/public and edit the code there and it seems to be working and updated the site. I am not sure how long this fix is for but it works for now.

Comment: If I may ask if I wanted to use ssh to clear cache, how do I go about doing that? what folder do I target in the terminal to use the `php artisan cache:clear`?